# Typescript Interface Type Variable, implement within an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an interface with a type variable:

```
interface MyObjectInterface<T> {
   aProp: keyof T;
}
```

Later, in my component, how would I provide a different type variable for each array element?

```
objects: MyObjectInterface[] = [
  {
    aProp: 'test'
  }
]
```

Comment: Each element has different type? what is your expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're saying is that you want to have an array of values of type `MyObjectInterface<T>`, each with an arbitrary `T`, and type the whole array as `MyObjectInterface[]`.

That's not how it works. When you define the type `MyObjectInterface<T>`, the type is not `MyObjectInterface` with the added quality that there is a generic parameter; the type **is** `MyObjectInterface<T>`. The type is inherently defined by the generic parameter itself. `MyObjectInterface<string>` and `MyObjectInterface<number>` are **not** different versions of the same type; they are different types.

What you could do is type the array not as `MyObjectInterface[]`, which is not a valid type, but as `MyObjectInterface<unknown>[]` or `MyObjectInterface<any>`, which would be. This would allow the items of the array to be typed with an arbitrary `T`, because by definition, any `T` would satisfy `unknown` or `any`.

Keep in mind, however, that doing this would cast every item in the array to `MyObjectInterface<unknown>` or `MyObjectInterface<any>`, causing you to lose the more specific type information for each item. Using `any` would allow you to reference the values of type `T` without actually knowing what `T`. Instead, you likely should use `unknown`, which would make you check what `T` is before you reference those values. Going from your question, I think this is probably what you're looking for, but you should consider what would actually be suitable for your particular use case.

Comment: `MyObjectInterface<unknown>` will at least force type checking of `T` if it's referenced later.

Comment: I always forget about `unknown`! Yeah, I suppose that would be marginally better than `any` in abstract. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I see, thank you. I guess I was confused and thought the <T> was more like a traditional parameter or argument. Are you saying I can use <unknown> then pass a type for each element when initializing the array? If so, how?